# Loop through all check boxes, weather it is checked or unchecked in PHP

Tags: php

My problem is that the below code changes the value of the checked ones, but the index i is assigned to the checked ones only. I want it to pass through all check boxes. For examples if the first and last check boxes were checked, I am getting `job[0]` is "yes" and `job[1]` is "yes" and the rest are "no" while I should get "yes" for `job[0]` and `job[4]`.

Code below:

```
if(!empty($_POST['job'])){

        $i = 0;
        $jobArray = array("no","no","no","no","no");

        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['job'] as $selected){
            $jobArray[$i] = "yes";
            $i++;
        }
    } //$_POST['job']
```

Comment: Cause you're currently looping on the checked value i guess.

Comment: Yes true, how do I loop through all?

Comment: A checkbox will only exist in the $_POST if it was checked.

Comment: You have to get all the checkbox value not using the $_POST. Since what @gview mentioned is true.

Comment: Okay. How do I get the check boxes without using $_POST? and if I did that, isn't it insecure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that checkboxes values exist in your request only if they are checked. You should keep it in mind.

So, you can change your application logic to work with that. But if you really need to have an array with 'yes', 'no' values, just create it.

Let's say you create your checkboxes like so:

```
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="job[<?= $i ?>]" value="yes">
    <?php endfor; ?>
```

Then, in your code:

```
    $jobs = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $jobs[$i] = $_POST['job'][$i] ?? 'no';
    }
```